# Can I get zsh-style path interpolation/completion in windows git bash?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, tab-completion

On my Linux machine I have used a nice zsh feature to complete multipart paths with a single tab press:

```
$ cd /h/p<tab>
  ->
$ cd /home/plato
```

I am currently developing in a Windows environment, using Git Bash.

Is there any way I can replicate this behavior, complete paths without typing out the first parts completely?

Comment: The question is can you install `zsh` on Windows and use it instead of `bash`.

Comment: no, although that's a pretty good question too :)

Comment: No, that is the question. The completion you are asking for is a zsh feature. I don't believe bash has anything like it (nor should that be the main question).

Comment: i asked the question to document a bash solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `complete` command to run a custom function when you press tab. Add these lines to .bashrc:

```
# Solution written by izabera on freenode. tyvm!
#.bashrc
myfunction () {
  local path oldpath ng=$(shopt -p nullglob)
  shopt -s nullglob
  printf -v path %q "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  oldpath=$path
  path=${path//\//*/} path=${path#\*}
  eval "COMPREPLY=($path*)"
  if (( ${#COMPREPLY[@]} == 0 )); then COMPREPLY=("$oldpath"); fi
  eval "$ng"
}

complete -D -F myfunction -o bashdefault -o default -o filenames
```

edit:
the -D flag was introduced in bash 4.1, the current bash version used by git-bash is 3.1.1.
The flag sets the completion function as the default, for any command that does not already have a completion function defined.

On 3.1.1, the best you can do is configure specific commands:

```
#.bashrc
myfunction () { ... }
complete -F myfunction -o bashdefault -o default -o filenames cd ls cp mv node npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I am the author of the project

This project enables the desired completion in bash: https://github.com/sio/bash-complete-partial-path

It works just fine on Windows with Git bash. Hope you'll find it useful